# Python: Is there a way to randomly split data from pandas dataframe into train and validation set

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning

I have a sparse matrix each columns contains price of a future. I hope to randomly split the data into two sets.
I understand that train_test_split in sklearn can randomly split data into two sets, however, it cannot satisfy my needs:

1. The randomly selected data should exclude nans
2. Extracting different size of data from each column.(eg.first column contains 10000 not nan cells,second contains 5000, I need to extract 2000 cells from first column and 500 from second column as train set, rest as validation set)

Is there time saving way to do this?

Comment: You should probably just use `pd.Series.sample()` with different values of sampling for different columns and then concatenate resulting columns into a dataframe.

Comment: What does `sparse matrix` have to do with pandas dataframe?  Seriously consider casting your data into a form that `sklearn` can easily split.  If it can't split it, it probably can't learn from it either.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I think the pd.Series.sample() still cannot exclude nans, it doesn't matter what kind of data form should be used, I just need to achieve the above mentioned goals without using too many loops

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
# Randomize the dataset
data_randomized = sms_spam.sample(frac=1, random_state=1)

# Calculate index for split 80:20 ratio
training_test_index = round(len(data_randomized) * 0.8)

# Split into training and test sets
training_set = data_randomized[:training_test_index].reset_index(drop=True)
test_set = data_randomized[training_test_index:].reset_index(drop=True)

print(training_set.shape)
print(test_set.shape)
```

source : [link](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2020/07/spam-filter-python-naive-bayes-scratch.html)